# Configure Wireguard to access LAN but don't route internet traffic through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, ethernet, wireguard

Currently I have access to LAN through wireguard and internet.
How to configure wg0 to have access to LAN but don't route internet traffic through VPN ?

**My current config (wg0):**

```
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = {key}
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
MTU = 1500

[Peer]
PublicKey = {key}
PresharedKey = {key}
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = {key}
PresharedKey = {key}
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = {key}
PresharedKey = {key}
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = {key}
PresharedKey = {key}
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.5/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = {key}
PresharedKey = {key}
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32
```

**Example client config:**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = {key}
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 10.0.0.4/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1


[Peer]
PublicKey = {key}
PresharedKey = {key}
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = 11.11.111.98:51820
```

Comment: That's a server config. Please post your client config, too. whats in the parameter AllowedIPs of your client? please remove keys.

Comment: @dummyuser edited. Please check now.

Comment: The parameter `AllowedIPs` in your client config defines which IPs should be reached via VPN right now you you send all IPs into the VPN. You ned to know which IPs to be reached via VPN e.G. `AllowedIPs = 172.16.1.0/24,192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24,192.168.4.0/24,2022:beef:db8::/64`

Comment: @dummyuser please explain. I don't understand what should be in 'AllowedIPs'

Comment: You do not want to route internet traffic through your VPN, correct? In terms of IP Addresses “Internet Traffic” means all destination IPs. Your current definition of `AllowedIPs` in the client config means route all destination IPs (=all Internet Traffic) through the VPN. 

1) Define exactly which destination IPs to be routed though your VPN and adopt the value of the `AllowedIPs` in you client config. 

2) AllowedIPs needs a comma separated list of target networks to be reached through the VPN

See manpage of wireguard of samples for more info

Comment: ok fixed. Works 